# Is for loop disabled in Firefox console?

Tags: javascript, firefox, console

This loop works fin in `node.js`

```
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

But no results in the Firefox console.
Has something changed in Firefox that disables looping?

Comment: Have you tried a simple `console.log("Hello")` statement without a for loop? It's possible you've filtered the console and you can't see the output from the logs. It's also possible that the website is overriding the `console.log` and doesn't log your calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this directly in Firefox console, you can try the below stuff. If you are running webpage with javascript, its most likely that the Javascript doesn't reach that part and execute the code

When you press enter for new line in Firefox console, it runs whatever you typed in the console.You can make the function inline

[image]

If you type this: `for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) { console.log(i);}` Firefox console will printout the values

If you wish support for multiline, you have to press Shift+Enter to get a new line in Firefox console. Below is a code that you can copy and paste into the console and will be multiline

```
for (let i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like the console was not refreshing. I had it in pop-out and when I closed and re-opened by accident, the loop ran fine.